# makefile fatal error: no such file or directory, but the file is in current directory

Tags: c, makefile, directory, header-files, fatal-error

I'm trying to make a very simple makefile for some .c and .h files, all of which are in the current directory. I will admit I don't fully understand makefile; here's what I have so far:

```
prog3 : prog3.c prog3.h lib.o
    gcc -c prog3.c

lib.o : lib.c lib.h
    gcc -c lib.c
```

When I use the command `make` I get this message:

```
prog3.c:5:17: fatal error: lib.c: No such file or directory  
compilation terminated.  
makefile:2: recipe for target 'prog3' failed  
make: *** [prog3] Error 1
```

The file `lib.c`, however, is in the same directory as all the others (`prog3.c`, `prog3.h`, `lib.h`).

I have found a lot of questions about this particular error, but none of them are about a file that is in the PWD. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try running the command yourself in the terminal, in order. `gcc -c lib.c` first and then `gcc -c prog3.c`. Does it shed light on the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your makefile looks fine. The basic structure of a makefile contains this pattern:

```
<build object> : <list of dependencies>
       command to execute to build the object if dependencies have changed
           ...
       command to execute to build the object if dependencies have changed
```

Your makefile is trying to compile prog3.c, which is what it is supposed to do. You have a compile error in prog3.c and it looks like you are trying to #include "lib.c", but my guess is that your are doing this on line 15:

```
#include <lib.c>
```

If this is what you are doing, this is wrong. C implementation files should never include other .c files (there are rare exceptions). You should only include .h header files. The linker will bring in the required functions from lib.c based on compiling against lib.h.

Also note that include files with brackets <> are for system headers only. User defined header files should be included using quotes:

```
#include "lib.h"
```

If this does not fix your compile error, edit your question to provide the prog3.c and lib.c files if you want those checked.

Comment: the problem was the quotes on lib.h, i think! i had brackets. rookie mistake... thank you so much!